# Fatal error : dispatch() on null magento 2

Tags: magento2

How to identify where and why this error is coming from mu custom module?

Call to a member function dispatch() on null in `C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2x\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock.php on line 644`

Comment: My front end page is showing blank without any errors, developermode enabled :   system .log says:  Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_frontend_STORE1_3d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e and handles : Please correct the XML data and try again.

Comment: May be your Magento does not install properly

Comment: Amit, its installed from git hub and other errors and results are coming fine!

Comment: What does this mean:                                                                                       Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_frontend_STORE1_3d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e and handles : Please correct the XML data and try again.

Comment: may be your block or controller use improper class.

Comment: anyway to find out from which Block as i get blank screen